# jQuery $.GET parameters passing in the URL

Tags: jquery, parameters, get

this is a general-purpose way to make GET requests with jQuery:

```
var loadUrl="mypage.php";
$("#get").click(function(){   
    $("#result").html(ajax_load);   
    $.get(   
        loadUrl,   
        {language: "php", version: 5},   
        function(responseText){   
            $("#result").html(responseText);   
        },   
        "html"  
    );   
});
```

I was wondering if I could pass parameters (Ex.language and version) directly in the URL(after urlencoding them):

```
var loadUrl="mypage.php?language=php&version=5";
$("#get").click(function(){   
    $("#result").html(ajax_load);   
    $.get(   
        loadUrl,      
        function(responseText){   
            $("#result").html(responseText);   
        },   
        "html"  
    );   
});
```

Is that possible? And anyhow which is the cleanest solution to make an ajax call  if I have all of the parameters I need urlencoded (Ex.`<a href="mypage.php?language=php&version=5">rate me</a>`)

Comment: Have you tried it? The answer is, yes, it will work, but its not the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes that is possible but you can also do it this way.

```
$.get(
   "mypage.php", 
   { version: "5", language: "php" }, // put your parameters here
   function(responseText){
      console.log(responseText);
   },
   'html'
);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$.get(

  url: url,    //your url eg. mypage.php

  data: data,   // Parameter you want to pass eg. {version:"5" , language : "php"}

  success: callback // function after success

);
```

follow the below link

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/