# Passing unique values via GET using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php

I'm echoing a table where each link has a unique value, which is `value='$passthisvalue'` as demonstrated in the example below. I'm trying to pass `value='$passthisvalue'` (maybe value should be called data-type instead?) when clicking each link with no page refresh. The value should be passed to `note.php` via GET.

php:

```
echo "<a href='#note' class='note' value='$passthisvalue' title='note'><img src='note.png' alt='note' title='note' border='0'></a>";
```

javascript:

```
<script>
$(".note").click(function() {
   var elem = $(this);
   $.get("note.php?value=$passthisvalue", function() {
      refreshthediv();
   }); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: Seems like duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383222/jquery-get-parameters-passing-in-the-url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the PHP script. If you want to use the passed value then use `$(this).attr('value')`.

Try with this:

```
<script>
$(".note").click(function() {
    var elem = $(this);
    //var passthisvalue = "<?php echo $passthisvalue;?>";
    //OR  
    passthisvalue = elem.attr('value');

    //$.get("note.php?value="+passthisvalue, function() {
    //    refreshthediv();
    //}); 
    //OR

    $.get("note.php", { value : passthisvalue }, function() {
        refreshthediv();
    });  
});
</script>
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot and accept if it works. Thank you so much.

Comment: That won't work. `a` elements do not have a `value` attribute and jQuery won't support `val()` for it.

Comment: @Quentin, Thinking about the script, i make a mistake and did the foolish work, Now changed to `attr`.

Comment: @michelleisconfused, There is no confusion after all, This is clear now, You can test it, after testing let me know is it useful or not.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should add `data-value`  to your `a` tag. it might help try the snippet below.

```
echo "<a href='#note' class='note' data-value='$passthisvalue' title='note'><img src='note.png' alt='note' title='note' border='0'></a>";

<script>
$(".note").click(function() {

var passthisvalue = $(this).data('value');
$.get("note.php", { value : passthisvalue }, function() {
    refreshthediv();
 }); 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Link to what you actually want to link to:

```
<a href='note.php?value=$passthisvalue' class='note' title='note'><img src='note.png' alt='note' title='note' border='0'></a>
```

And then read the `href` attribute with JavaScript.

```
$(".note").click(function(event) {
       event.preventDefault()
       $.get(this.href, refreshthediv);
   }); 
});
```

Comment: You change the `<a ...>` as you want whether you can did this using javaScript / jQuery only.

Comment: @FrayneKonok — That's because it makes more sense to write quality HTML and JavaScript to deal with it then it does to write invalid HTML and write JavaScript to work around the errors.

Comment: You are right, but the OP use a `#note` in the `href` so how can you change it? that may be some business.

Comment: I can't talk over you cause i don't have such kind of intelligence , I am just starter.